# Xamarin UI Design - Xaml ToolBox

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-emulator

Hello Every one  iam  a beginner in **Xamarin - Cross platforms**

so when i downloaded it and starts to work on it ,    it has not  a UI ToolBox  like  the Android Studio   like a Mobile Device  which we Drag and drop the items and start to code    thats what i mean

is there some thing like that in Xaml -Xamarin Portable Shared  platforms

Or a Plugin  in **NuGet**   Display a ToolBox  with drag and drop  in Portable  App  [Andrid - Windows phone - IOS ]  all togethet

Comment: No. But it does have xaml preview but that is also not as good as android studio preview window.

Comment: For anyone who finds this thread, the answers provided through 2018 are no longer accurate: "Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8 and Visual Studio for Mac 7.6 now have a Toolbox available while editing Xamarin.Forms XAML files. The toolbox contains all the built-in Xamarin.Forms controls and layouts, which can be dragged into the XAML editor." Ref:  <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/toolbox?tabs=windows>

Answer (score 0):

There is no drag and drop in xamarin ,you need to code front end manually.
Xamarin has a xaml preview to show how the UI you coded looks.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms does not support drag and drop, use xaml for designing the UI which is very easy to learn and use Xamarin Live Player to see the changes. you can get all the information from the link below: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin now has a toolbox which can be used for frontend development, you can drag and drop your controls and layouts in XAML file now.

You can go to View > Toolbox to navigate to the toolbox. For further information you can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/toolbox?tabs=windows).